# 2 AutoCompleteTextView's, how to know which view has been selected

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

It may seem like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935897/autocompletetextview-how-to-determine-which-item-of-original-list-was-selected), but it ain't.

I have 2 `AutoCompleteTextView`'s in my layout. From Address, To Address. I need to know which one of them initiated the drop down list.

Since both were using the same item layout, I duplicated it and tried, still no luck.

Initialization of `AutoCompleteTextView`'s

```
    fromAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(this, R.layout.fromautocomplete);
    fromAutoComplete.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    fromAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fromAddress);
    fromAddress.setAdapter(fromAutoComplete);
    fromAddress.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    fromAddress.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    toAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(this, R.layout.toautocomplete);
    toAutoComplete.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    toAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.toAddress);
    toAddress.setAdapter(toAutoComplete);
    toAddress.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    toAddress.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**Notice the R.layout.toautocomplete and R.layout.fromautocomplete**

Both are identical as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:minLines="3"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:textSize="15dp" 
android:text="sample text"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

To debug the values, I have put some Log statements

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View who, int position, long id) {
    Log.e("Taxeeta", ">"+parent.getId()+":"+who.getId()+":"+id) ;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      
    Log.e("Taxeeta", parent.getId()+":"+view.getId()+":"+id) ;
}
```

Output of log is

> 07-02 17:24:14.773: E/Taxeeta(12103): -1:-1:0

Frankly, this just sucks, why would id's for parent, view and id return such useless values ?

I am missing something really basic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The answer is 2 fold.

1. The `id` value returned by `onItemClick` returns **0** for the first autocomplete, and **1** for the second autocomplete

   > 07-02 17:24:14.773: E/Taxeeta(12103): -1:-1:0
   >
   > 07-02 17:24:14.773: E/Taxeeta(12103): -1:-1:1
2. The layout textview's should have id's. That is returned in the **view** parameter of `onItemClick`

For FromLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fromautocomplete"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:minLines="3"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:textSize="15dp" 
android:text="sample text"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

For ToLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toautocomplete"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:minLines="3"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:textSize="15dp" 
android:text="sample text"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```